# Windows Phone - Finding child items within canvas

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, canvas, parent-child

I have *n* canvases in a list, and I need to find the Properties of a TextBlock within the canvas in C# when it is tapped, the .xaml code is as follows

```
<Canvas Height="175" Width="360" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Name="canvasNote" Tap="canvasNote_Tap">
   <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
      <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False">
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Open" Click="hubTileOpen_Click"/>
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="hubTileEdit_Click"/>
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="hubTileDelete_Click"/>
      </toolkit:ContextMenu>
   </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="12,4,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" Margin="12,28,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="352" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
</Canvas>
```

Any ideas?

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways. One way is to set the `x:Name` property of the textblocks, and retrieve them using the `FindName` method:

```
<Canvas Height="175" Width="360" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Name="canvasNote" Tap="canvasNote_Tap">
   <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
      <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False">
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Open" Click="hubTileOpen_Click"/>
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="hubTileEdit_Click"/>
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="hubTileDelete_Click"/>
      </toolkit:ContextMenu>
   </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="12,4,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
   <TextBlock x:Name="Details" Text="{Binding Details}" Margin="12,28,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="352" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then in the `Tap` event:

```
private void canvasNote_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = (Canvas)sender;

    var title = (TextBlock)canvas.FindName("Title");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(title.Text);
}
```

But since you're using *n* canvases without using datatemplates, you may run into name collisions. So an alternative way is to use the `Tag` property instead:

```
<Canvas Height="175" Width="360" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Name="canvasNote" Tap="canvasNote_Tap">
   <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
      <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False">
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Open" Click="hubTileOpen_Click"/>
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="hubTileEdit_Click"/>
         <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="hubTileDelete_Click"/>
      </toolkit:ContextMenu>
   </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   <TextBlock Tag="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="12,4,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
   <TextBlock Tag="Details" Text="{Binding Details}" Margin="12,28,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="352" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
</Canvas>
```

And in the `Tap` event:

```
private void canvasNote_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = (Canvas)sender;

    var title = canvas.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().First(t => (t.Tag as string) == "Title");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(title.Text);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have said; that wasn't the full section of code, it is within a listbox, with a data template. However the first section you wrote worked like a charm, thanks very much!